# Can instances of a constructor inherit members that are not defined within the prototype bucket?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototype

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#The_prototype_property_Where_inherited_members_are_defined) explains that the instances of a constructor only inherit members within the constructor.prototype property, but not anything outside of it. For example, `Object.prototype.watch()` will be inherited to its instance, but not `Object.keys();`.

If I have a constructor as follows:

```
function Person(name) {
this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
 alert("Hi!");
}
```

the name property is not inside the prototype property, but the greeting() method is.  However, if I create an instance as such:

```
let person1 = new Person("Foo");
```

person1 is able to access `person1.name` as well as `person1.greeting()` both even though the name property is defined outside of the prototype property.

Comment: As in `Person.prototype.greeting()`. I don't know, what _are_ you missing? By the way, you have a syntax error. It's supposed to be `Person.prototype.greeting = function () { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the answer is yes: an instance can inherit from the prototype object property of its constructor, as well as *any properties that the prototype object inherits.* This is the generalized meaning of the "prototype chain".

In the case of the example given however, the confusion arises in believing `name` is inherited - it is not.

Objects can have local or "own" properties in addition to inheriting properties from their prototype chain. Ignoring more advanced usage of  getters and setters, inherited properties are read only: if you write to them the value written is held in an "own" property created to locally hold the value written - meaning the value written shadows the inherited value without overwriting it in place.

For more information please research how JavaScript inheritance works and in particular what the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` method does.

Answer (score 1):

The property and `name` and method `greeting` both are available to the `person1` in different ways.

1. `name` is available to `person1` because of `new` operator
2. `greeting` is available to `person1` because of `prototype`

When `new` operator is used it always returns a `Object`. And object have its own properties. `name` is the property of Object.